# Problems of while(true) in C# "VS2012" {WinForm}

Tags: c#, multithreading, winforms, loops, visual-studio-2012

```
" int ans = 2;

    private void Form1_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        for (int i = 0; i <21; i++)
        {
            ans = 2;
            label1.Text += i.ToString();
            while (true)
            {
                if (ans == 1)
                {
                    break;
                }
            }
        }

    }

    private void button1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        ans = 1;
    } "
```

this  is a simple app

I want to print a number & then wait to the button to be clicked to break the  while loop

but when I run the application , the form doesn't show .

"T think that the problem is the while (true)".

what to do?

Comment: You are right. The loop will never end and so your app will remain in the Form1_Load, unable to do anything else. What are you trying to do?

Comment: Form1_Load is an event handler for the form loading, if you want to do things before the form has loaded - this is the place. for other things this is not the place. If you do for some reason need something to run forever (which I doubt) try starting a new thread, otherwise try a timer!

Comment: as alex said, use a timer. Start the timer in form_load. When the timer ticks, increment the number. When the button is pressed stop the timer.

Comment: why not `async` with `await Task.Delay` ?

Answer (score 3):

Use a timer. Start the timer when the form loads. Each time it ticks, increment the number and display it. On button click, you just need to stop the timer.

```
private Timer _myTimer;
private int number = 0;
private void Form1_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    _myTimer = new Timer();
    _myTimer.Interval = 1; // 1 millisecond
    _myTimer.Tick += new EventHandler(MyTimer_Tick);
    _myTimer.Start();
}

// increments the number at timer tick
private void MyTimer_Tick(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    number ++;
    // TODO: update UI here
}

// Stops the timer
private void button1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    _myTimer.Stop();
}
```

Answer (score 0):

It's best to not use a loop here. Since this loop won't end you won't ever leave Form_Load and it won't display the form. If you were trying to do some task when the user clicks a button, why not move that logic to `button1_Click`?

Answer (score 0):

The correct way to implement such a task as you describe would be as such:

```
    private EventWaitHandle ewh = new EventWaitHandle(false, EventResetMode.AutoReset);

    private void Form1_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        Task.Factory.StartNew(() =>
        {
            for (int i = 0; i < 26; i++)
            {
                ewh.WaitOne();
                Action updateLable = () => label1.Text = "" + i;
                label1.BeginInvoke(updateLable);
            }
        });
    }

    private void button1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        ewh.Set();
    }
```

As you can see I've replaced your [busy wait](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Busy_waiting) (while(true)) with a .Net [wait handle](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/kad9xah9(v=vs.110).aspx).

One of the answers describes a timer that acts every millisecond - that is a busy wait of sorts.

Answer (score 0):

This is what **[async/await](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/hh191443.aspx)** is for.  Mark your Load() event with "async", then "await" a Task that continues when a ManualResetEvent is triggered in the Button click handler:

```
    private System.Threading.ManualResetEvent mre = new System.Threading.ManualResetEvent(false);

    private async void Form1_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        for (int i = 0; i < 21; i++)
        {
            label1.Text = i.ToString();
            mre.Reset();
            await Task.Factory.StartNew(() => { mre.WaitOne(); });
        }
        button1.Enabled = false;
        label1.Text = "Done!";
    }

    private void button1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        mre.Set();
    }
```