# While loop doesn't stop after Boolean is changed

Tags: c#, winforms

I am working with a small experiment project with windows form application and I got a problem with while loop, after button click. After I click button2 the boolean `b` should be changed to false and the loop should stop but it isn't.

```
namespace Spalvos
{
    public partial class Form1 : Form
    {
        public Form1()
        {
            InitializeComponent();
        }
        Boolean b;
        private void button1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            b = true;
            while (b == true) {
                Random rnd = new Random();
                int r = rnd.Next(0, 254);
                int n = rnd.Next(0, 254);
                int d = rnd.Next(0, 254);

                this.BackColor = Color.FromArgb(r, n, d);
                Application.DoEvents();
                System.Threading.Thread.Sleep(200);              
            }
        }

        private void button2_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            b = false;
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Problems of while(true) in C# "VS2012" {WinForm}](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/31896721/problems-of-whiletrue-in-c-sharp-vs2012-winform)

Comment: Don't use `DoEvents`.  It's a hangover from the VB days.  If you want to do something in the 'background', either start a thread, or use a timer.

Comment: Or a duplicate of https://stackoverflow.com/questions/27580241/breaking-from-a-loop-with-button-click-c-sharp

Comment: Could you put your code in the correct format please ?

Comment: You should not initialize `rnd` inside the loop like that, since it uses the system clock to create a default seed value. Instead you should just declare it at class scope and initialize it once for the best random results.

Comment: Your code works fine for me. What is the problem?

Comment: A variable used in this fashion should probably be [marked volatile](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/72275/when-should-the-volatile-keyword-be-used-in-c).

Comment: I click button1 and  color loop starts but after I click button2 it does'nt stop(it should stop)

Comment: It stops if you click and re-click fast enough

Comment: @JohnWu From your link: "I discourage you from ever making a volatile field" So why do you think that applies here, especially since I don't seen indication of multithreading in the OP?

Comment: @KennethK. Because of potential compiler optimizations that would preclude the Button1_Click handler from seeing any changes made from outside the immediate code block.

Comment: @JohnWu Again, there's no indication of multi-threading here, so why would that apply? Everything that I'm finding on the web points to `volatile` being important in multi-threaded apps. Even [the documentation](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/previous-versions/visualstudio/visual-studio-2010/x13ttww7(v=vs.100)) states "volatile keyword indicates that a field might be modified by multiple threads that are executing at the same time". Event handlers aren't (by default) multi-threaded in WinForms.

Answer (score 3):

Your code works but it's a little flaky; events from Button2 sometimes get lost or delayed, possibly because of the way you are intermingling calls to `Sleep()` and `DoEvents`, and use of DoEvents is highly discouraged, and superannuated by the introduction of `async` and `await`. Also, you should only initialize your `Random` one time (unless you are doing something really weird).

You can get a much better and more modern solution if you make your click handler async, like so:

```
    private volatile Boolean b;

    private async void button1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        Random rnd = new Random();

        b = true;
        while (b)
        {
            int r = rnd.Next(0, 254);
            int n = rnd.Next(0, 254);
            int d = rnd.Next(0, 254);

            this.BackColor = Color.FromArgb(r, n, d);
            await Task.Delay(200);
        }
    }

    private void button2_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        b = false;
    }
}
```

This solution has its problems too, however. Imagine what would happen if you clicked Button1 twice, for example. Probably not what was intended.

I would suggest you move the logic to change colors to a [timer control](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.windows.forms.timer?redirectedfrom=MSDN&view=netframework-4.7.2), and use the `Button1` event handler to enable it and the `Button2` event handler to disable it.

```
public Form1()
{
    InitializeComponent();
    this.timer1.Interval = 200;
}

private Random rnd = new Random();

private void button1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    this.timer1.Enabled = true;
}

private void button2_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    this.timer1.Enabled = false;
}

private void timer1_Tick(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    int r = rnd.Next(0, 254);
    int n = rnd.Next(0, 254);
    int d = rnd.Next(0, 254);

    this.BackColor = Color.FromArgb(r, n, d);
}
```

Isn't that much simpler?

Comment: Thank you for your help.

Answer (score 0):

In your code you are invoking **Thread.Sleep** method on the UI thread. This will result in blocking the UI. You could check it by expanding the millisecond value in the **Thread.Sleep**.

To make UI responsive, you using hack Application.DoEvents(). Which stops all other threads and invokes all methods which are waiting (in this example are blocked by the loop). Without it after running the application, your form will be frozen and you won't be able to click button or move the window.

This is not correct way of writing the code. Application should do the most consuming work in the background and only switch for short time to perform operation on the UI.

Good way is to start while loop in the background, calculate color in the background and use delegate to switch to UI when needed.

```
delegate void ChangeColorDelegate(Color c);
public partial class Form1 : Form
{
    Thread thread;
    Boolean b;
    Random Random;

    public Form1()
    {
        InitializeComponent();
        thread = new Thread(ChangeColorBackground);
        thread.Start();
        Random = new Random();
    }

    private void button1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        b = true;
    }

    private void button2_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        b = false;
    }

    private void ChangeColorBackground()
    {
        while (true)
        {
            if (b == true)
            {
                int r = Random.Next(0, 254);
                int n = Random.Next(0, 254);
                int d = Random.Next(0, 254);
                Color c = Color.FromArgb(r, n, d);
                ChangeColorThreadSafe(c);
            }
            System.Threading.Thread.Sleep(100);
        }
    }

    private void ChangeColorThreadSafe(Color c)
    {
        if (button1.InvokeRequired)
        {
            ChangeColorDelegate delgate = new ChangeColorDelegate(ChangeColorThreadSafe);
            button1.Invoke(delgate, new object[] { c });
        }
        else
        {
            this.BackColor = c;
        }
    }
}
```

I created the example on [github](https://github.com/pwujczyk/ProductivityTools.Examples.Winforms.ChangeBackgroundColor).

Comment: `Random rnd = new Random();` should never be inside a loop.